# как при создании окна tkinter обновлять его содержимое?

Tags: python, tkinter

Как после создания окна менять его содержимое? Допустим ситуация, когда в окне показывается список людей онлайн в чате. Как сделать так, чтобы он обновлялся по мере захода\выхода людей из сети? 
Я только сейчас познакомился с Tkinter и не нашел как это осуществить
Команда вызова окна mainloop() приостанавливает выполнение программы. А для того чтобы обновлять содержимое нужно чтобы программа после открытия окна продолжала свое выполнение. Подскажите как такое можно осуществить. Скорее всего все уже придумали, просто я не знаю как это сделать. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: в чём у вас конкретная проблема? Вас интересует какой метод у виджета может текст его изменить? Вас интересует как сетевое приложение написать (чат)? Как его интегрировать с tkinter? Попробуйте сузить вопрос.¶ Если хочется всего и сразу, [вот наивная попытка чата на чистых сокетах, c потоками и tkinter GUI](https://medium.com/swlh/lets-write-a-chat-app-in-python-f6783a9ac170).  Вот [пример кода, как вывод внешнего процесса в GUI отображается без использования потоков](https://gist.github.com/zed/9294978)

Comment: @jfs хватит портить мне репутацию. Вы могли бы добавить ответ и про потоки, но, я считаю, здесь (как начинающему программировать человеку) абсолютно необходимо знать что такое событие и как с ним работать.

Comment: Мой комментарий, просит автора уточнить вопрос (менее обширным сделать), чтобы можно было бы содержательный ответ дать, который был бы полезным как автору так и будущим посетителям из гугла с похожей проблемой (подавляющее большинство траффика ~95%). К вам я не обращался и не  вижу какое отношение ваш комментарий к моему имеет. Если вас вдруг моё мнение стало интересовать, начните с того, чтобы [исправлять ошибки, когда вам на них указывают.](https://goo.gl/vuKGHk)

Comment: Проблема была в том, что я не знал как обновить список пользователей онлайн. Нужно создать собственное событие, которое реагирует на информацию приходящую с сервера?

Answer (score 2):

Есть [документация](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tkinter.html) на такие вопросы.
Когда Вы создаёте какой-то экземпляр, вы можете привязать какое либо событие с функцией и с объектом.
Например(пример из документации):

```py
button = Button(root)
def turn_red(self, event):
    event.widget["activeforeground"] = "red"

button.bind("<Enter>", self.turn_red)
```

Существует [набор](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) предустановленных событий.

### Но как создать свои собственные события?

Собственные события называются *виртуальные события* и вот как их делать:

```py
root = Tk()
root.event_add('<<virtual>>')
```

Можно ещё "наследовать" события:

```py
root.event_add('<<virtual>>', '<Enter>', '<Esc>')  # создаёт событие на одновременное нажатие Esc и Enter
```

Также можно вызывать события искуствено:

```py
root.event_generate('<<virtual>>')
```

Также можно добавить именованные аргументы, чтобы заменить аргументы события по умолчанию:

```py
root.event_generate('<<virtual>>', keyword=value)
```

Comment: как описать функционал виртуального события? и как его вызвать не просто со стартом окна, а периодически, чтобы динамически обновлять  данные?

Comment: @Алексей функционал? У события нет функционала, это всего лишь "раздражитель". А "иммунитет" уже будет что-либо делать. Иными словами, вы сами должны показывать как и где реагировать на данные "раздражители". К сожалению, Вы не можете создавать события в некоторых случаях, но сомневаюсь, что Вы с ними встретитесь.

Comment: мне нужно, чтобы раздражителем выступали данные пришедшие на сокет от сервера. Такое сделать возможно?